# Link and Route in separate components

Tags: react-router

In my React app, I have the following component structure:
[image]

The problem is that I cannot get the `<Route .../>` in **App.js** refresh, when I click on the `<Link/>` in the **AllLists.js**

All works fine, if I place **Sidebar.js** and **AllLists.js** code, hence the `<Link/>` tags in **App.js**

Is there no way to make `<Link/>` render a component higher in the component tree?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, minutes after posting the question. So here it is:

The `<Link/>` tag was under `<BrowserRouter/>` under **AllLists.js**. Replacing that `<BrowserRouter/>` with a simple `<div>` solved my problem!!